# Login Password validation in Spring Boot (BCryptPasswordEncoder) + Vue js (bcryptjs) not working?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Overview :

To validate Login credentials a POST API call is made from VueJs to Spring boot. To send password as hashed, in vue js bcryptjs is used.
and at spring boot end password are stored in DB are also hashed using BCryptPasswordEncoder.

Problem statement :

when hashed password received from Vue js is compared at spring boot end.
Below code does not match password as it Expects plainText e.g "myPassword12"
where as from vue js its coming as $2a$10$bvaf6ECxu7QvJl/B7puhTO3XOJibrkOR/VSVpygHnU84V.S8GHEse

Note : if we pass plaintext from vue js below check works.

this.passwordEncoder.matches(presentedPassword, userDetails.getPassword())

Here expectation is, password should send as encrypted from vue js to spring boot.
How to achieve this?
Let me know if any extra info need to be shared, Thanks in Advance.

//--------Spring inbuilt code-------------

```
package org.springframework.security.authentication.dao;
public class DaoAuthenticationProvider extends AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider {..

    protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails userDetails, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        if (authentication.getCredentials() == null) {
            this.logger.debug("Failed to authenticate since no credentials provided");
            throw new BadCredentialsException(this.messages.getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", "Bad credentials"));
        } else {
            String presentedPassword = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
            if (!this.passwordEncoder.matches(presentedPassword, userDetails.getPassword())) {
                this.logger.debug("Failed to authenticate since password does not match stored value");
                throw new BadCredentialsException(this.messages.getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", "Bad credentials"));
            }
        }
    }
```

--------Application code in Spring @Configuration class-----

```
@Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10);
    }

public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }
```

...

Vue js code:

```
    var epasswrd = bcrypt.hashSync(this.loginUser.password, 10);
    
    axios.post(process.env.API_BASE_URL + 'login', 'username=' + this.loginUser.username + '&password=' + epasswrd, {
                  headers: {
                    'cache-control': 'no-cache'
                  }
                }).then(function (response) { // do something }
```

Version:

Front End : Vue js
Back End : Spring boot 2.7